# Mongodb java driver aggregation's cursor don't have a skip method?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am querying the mongodb using mongodb-java-driver [aggregation api](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#aggregate-java.util.List-com.mongodb.AggregationOptions-). And I find when query the db in a aggregation way using `com.mongodb.DBCollection.aggregate` a [`cursor`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/Cursor.html) interface will be returned.

Here is the method signature:

```
com.mongodb.DBCollection
public com.mongodb.Cursor aggregate(java.util.List<com.mongodb.DBObject> pipeline,
                                    com.mongodb.AggregationOptions options)
```

But this returned `cursor` is not skip-able, ie, it doesn't have a `skip` method as the `DBCursor` class does. And the [official document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/#aggregation-cursors) don't give a hint of doing that.

Does that mean when I do a aggregate query, and when I want to do a  pagenation ,I can only retrieve the whole result set and skip the un-needed items myself?

Answer (score 0):

You could of course skip them yourself programmatically, but there is a way to do it:
[Aggregator skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/)

But you must skip with the aggregate, you can not skip afterwards (Then you would either need to aggregate again or skip programmatically)

```
{ $skip: <positive integer> }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$skip` in mongo aggregation also using java. Let's check following two links 
[mongo java aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)

and

[mongo $skip in aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/)

Using above two links you able to set your aggregation query as below

```
    // unwind  if required 
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$your unwind field");

// create  pipeline operations, with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("given key", "matching value"));

// Now the $group operation if required 
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$group field");
groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

// build the $projection operation
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
fields.put("count", "$count");
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);

// skip 
DBObject skip = new BasicDBObject("$skip", positive integer);

// run aggregation
List < DBObject > pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, group, project, skip);

AggregationOutput output = collectionName.aggregate(pipeline);
for (DBObject result: output.results()) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```